# Java Swing GUI hour glass

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, hour

There is a `JTabbedPane` In my *Swing* program.
When user clicks on a tab, the program takes a while to get the data and process the results, then shows the results in the selected tab.

**How can I display a hour glass, or something of that effect** so that user knows it's processing data? Not to click on the tab again before it finishes it job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [JProgressBar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) (possibly in indetermiante mode) sounds right - put that on the tab until the data has been fetched. A well-designed UI shouldn't force the user to wait for long-running tasks to complete and instead allow them to do something else inbetween.

Comment: To that end, I would hope that the long-running task is done in a separate thread.

Comment: I'll try this, makes sense, so user will know how long to wait.

Answer (score 26):

The simplest way is to just call [setCursor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor(java.awt.Cursor)) on the appropriate component (probably the top-level window) with the appropriate [Cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html).

```
component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
```

And then set it back when you are done.

```
component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
```

Comment: Great, it's simple and effective.

Answer (score 3):

setCursor(int) is deprecated. This is probably a bit cleaner:

```
setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mention, you can set a wait cursor, but you also mention preventing additional mouse clicks. You can use a glass pane to prevent clicks on components until the long operation is finished. In addition to the [Sun tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) on the glass pane, there is a nice example at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrateuseofGlassPane.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would as other mentioned

- Change the cursor
- Use a SwingWorker
- Display the progressbar or an animated image in the glasspane
- Hide the glasspane when the task is completed
- Restore the default cursor